# Is there a way to setup a notification from Unreal Engine when it finishes packaging / building my game?

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, scripting

In Unity I was able to use a post build script to send myself an email when Unity finishes building a game. Is there a way to make a script run when Unreal Engine is done packaging a game?

Or any other way to set up a notification sound or visual prompt in my Windows PC to alert me when it finishes packaging?

Comment: You can package with command line - thus you can make a script that will run the packaging and then will fire your notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. I recommend using Jenkins CI for automating Unreal Engine's RunUAT.bat.

There are great references here, if you are unfamiliar: https://github.com/skymapgames/jenkins-ue4/tree/master/build-scripts

Jenkins CI has an email extension (https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/) that will email you upon the completion of a pipeline. You can set up your build scripts to automate RunUAT.bat, build inside Jenkins CI, then use that plugin to email you upon completion. Hope this helps!